# Is it possible to wrap columns (that contain a single word) in the Oracle Apex Interactive Default Report PDF Export Option?

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am working in Oracle Apex 5.0.4.  I wanted to know if there is an option or if I can create a work-around to wrap text word (Eg. TwoParagraphsButNoWrap )  to fit in it's cell in the Oracle Apex Interactive Report PDF Export.

Currently with the example above, the text gets cut off at 'graphs'.  If there were spaces included like Two Paragraphs But No Wrap, then the text would wrap.  I cannot increase the column width since there are other columns included on the report.

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem?

Comment: @kapiell I have not found an out of the box solution (eg. Not creating custom reports) yet.   I am going to be asking around a little bit more, but if there is no other solution I will look into the Custom reports.

Comment: Sure, I tried to simulate your issue on apex.oracle.com but the text wrapped as expected.

Comment: I will try it out on apex.oracle to see if there is something wrong with our environment's setup.  But did the wrapping of a single word work with your custom suggestion or the default export?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating custom report layout, you will get more control on styling table cells.

Link to Oracle white paper on how to create custom pdf reports --> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/custom-pdf-reports-1953918.pdf